AzureDevOps Pipeline 'Classic Editor' not visible when trying to create a pipeline
I am trying to create a Pipeline in AzureDevOps for our Azure Data Factory CI/CD process. I would like to use the 'Classic Editor' to create the pipeline, see image.

However, when I select 'Create Pipeline' I am not given the option to use the Classic Editor, I get the following:

Can someone let me know how go activate the Classic Editor in our Azure DevOps please.
I am not able to see the release tab under pipelines, see image. Do I need additional permissions?

With the 'Release' tab being disabled, can someone let me know how I would view the following screen? Or would this all be built with YAML code?


email format to enable classic editor
to get permission to the organizational level on azure devops you have to an email in this format to azure team and this issue will resolve within 2 days

You can disable creation of classic pipelines by turning on two toggles at either organization level or project level.
To turn them on, navigate to your Organization / Project settings, then under the Pipelines section choose Settings. In the General section, toggle on Disable creation of classic build pipelines and Disable creation of classic release pipelines.
When you turn them on at organization level, it is on for all projects in that organization. If you leave them off, you can choose for which projects you wish to turn them on.


Thank you. I have just found out that my manager has disabled the creation of classic pipelines - which is very frustrating ... Thank you anyway

@Patterson it might be frustrating, but if I were in your manager's shoes I'd do exactly the same. It takes a bit of time to get used to the YAML pipelines but there are many advantages in using them as opposed to the classical build/release pipelines.

I understand that. I have built the pipeline from the following link using the classic editor. Would it be easy to follow the same process using YAML
https://iterationinsights.com/article/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-devops-pipelines/

It depends on how complex the pipeline is, and how much experience you have with YAML pipelines. Not sure if this exactly what you're looking for, but take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-bBMelqifw

The pipeline is quite simple, but I don't have a lot of experience with YAML.

I have updated the question to find out if I need additional permissions to be able to view the 'Release' tab under 'Pipelines'

@Patterson release pipelines are only for the classical pipelines, not YAML. You probably don't see it because the Disable creation of classic release pipelines flag is disabled.

Thank you @Rui, for you continued support with this. I have updated the question. Can you let me know if everything would be done with YAML. I wouldn't know where to start creating the Release with YAML

Regarding the first steps, please refer to the official documentation. Also, search for something on youtube or simply ask for help to any team member :-)


Go to organization settings
Then go to pipeline settings and disable below three options
Disable creation of classic build pipelines
Disable creation of classic release pipelines
Enable shell tasks arguments validation
and you good to go

REF: https://www.coachdevops.com/2024/01/how-to-enable-to-use-classic-editor-to.html#:~:text=In%20Azure%20DevOps%2C%20Go%20to,shown%20after%20creating%20a%20project.
